# Can we import dynamic table that in Snowflake stage to Power BI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake stage its a dynamic , how can I import that in Power BI , as it cannot be seen in database while connecting Power BI to snowflake. I have connected snowflake to Power BI and I can import data from the databases but I cannot import dynamic tables that stored in stage.

Comment: Do you mean external tables?

Answer (score 0):

The query is vague and the assumption here is that the file exists in stage(internal/external). It is possible to read data directly from stage as source for Power BI.

Stage could be queried as any other DB object.

> [Querying Data in Staged Files](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage)
>
> **Snowflake supports using standard SQL to query data files located in an internal (i.e. Snowflake) stage or named external (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure) stage.** This can be useful for inspecting/viewing the contents of the staged files, particularly before loading or after unloading data.
>
> This functionality is primarily for performing simple queries only, particularly when loading and/or transforming data, **and is not intended to replace loading data into tables and performing queries on the tables.**

---

Data preparation:

```
COPY INTO @~/test.csv
FROM (SELECT 1 AS col, 'b' AS col2 UNION
      SELECT 2,        'c')
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV);

LIST @~;
-- name size
-- test.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz    32

SELECT $1, $2
FROM @~/test.csv;
-- $1   $2
-- 1    b
-- 2    c
```

Power BI - using SQL statement text:

[image]

[image]